# client.list_time_series does not return JSON object

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using the google cloud python client library to retrieve monitoring metrics for my GKE cluster. I am running this python code on vscode, and taking output in a text file:

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = f"projects/{project_id}"

now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10**9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1200), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)

results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Some of the output is the following:

```
metric {
  type: "kubernetes.io/pod/network/sent_bytes_count"
}
resource {
  type: "k8s_pod"
  labels {
    key: "pod_name"
    value: "event-exporter-gke-755c4b4d97-449jj"
  }
  labels {
    key: "namespace_name"
    value: "kube-system"
  }
  labels {
    key: "location"
    value: "us-central1-c"
  }
  labels {
    key: "cluster_name"
    value: "cluster-1"
  }
}
metric_kind: CUMULATIVE
value_type: INT64
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1686546653
      nanos: 796780000
    }
    start_time {
      seconds: 1686497154
    }
  }
  value {
    int64_value: 4735157
  }
}
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1686546593
      nanos: 794737000
    }
    start_time {
      seconds: 1686497154
    }
  }
  value {
    int64_value: 4730649
  }
}
```

As you can see, this is almost JSON. But it should be JSON according to this:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics-details
Kindly help.
"TypeError: Object of type TimeSeries is not JSON serializable" is the error when I tried to use json.dump.

Comment: The results are a Python class, not a JSON object. When in doubt use built-in features such as `type()` or `isinstance()`, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley , I get that the result is a Python instance of the TimeSeries object, but shouldn't the output be in a json format, according to the link I mentioned? The problem is, without getting it into json, I will have difficulty parsing it.

Comment: What is printed: `print(type(result))`

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, it gives "TimeSeries". To parse it, I will have to look at the methods available for that instance. But I cannot find any documentation for that. For example, print(result.metadata.system_labels["node_name"]) is available but pylance isn't able to resolve after metadata. So I really don't know how the TimeSeries object is working.

Comment: You can always look at the Python source code for the class `TimeSeries`. There are simple Python tricks to figure out class members. Look into `print(vars(result))` and `print(dir(result))`. As you gain more experience with Python, this stuff becomes easy.